# Magnific popup - How to reference buttons within the modal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, magnific-popup

If I create a modal inline with buttons...I want to be able to perform a certain action when each is clicked. However, I am unable to grab hold of these buttons generated in the modal.

Does anyone know how I can grab these?

```
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    items: {
        type: 'inline',
        src: $('<div class="white-popup">\
                    <h4>Are you sure you were discharged for failing a drugs test?</h4>\
                    <p>You will not be able to change your answer once you have submitted these details.</p>\
                    <button id="test-popup-no">No, I\'ve made a mistake</button>\
                    <button id="test-popup-yes">Yes, I\'m sure</button>\
                    </div>')
    },
    type: 'inline',
    midClick: true
});
```

I'd like to perform different actions when each of the buttons is clicked depending on its ID.

Please help if you can. I've been struggling with this. Just doing a standard jQuery selection does not seem to work.

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try binding a click handler using event delegation with jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Code:

```
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    items: {
        type: 'inline',
        src: $('<div class="white-popup">\
                    <h4>Are you sure you were discharged for failing a drugs test?</h4>\
                    <p>You will not be able to change your answer once you have submitted these details.</p>\
                    <button id="test-popup-no">No, I\'ve made a mistake</button>\
                    <button id="test-popup-yes">Yes, I\'m sure</button>\
                    </div>')
    },
    type: 'inline',
    midClick: true
});

$('body').on('click','#test-popup-no', function(){
    alert('Nope!');    
})

$('body').on('click','#test-popup-yes', function(){
    alert('Yes');    
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/A9dQ7/

Answer (score 4):

The code posted by @Irvin is valid, but not very good in terms of app performance. I'd recommend to use open/close callbacks to bind/unbind click events, e.g.:

```
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    items: {
        type: 'inline',
        src: $('<div class="white-popup">\
                    <h4>Are you sure you were discharged for failing a drugs test?</h4>\
                    <p>You will not be able to change your answer once you have submitted these details.</p>\
                    <button id="test-popup-no">No, I\'ve made a mistake</button>\
                    <button id="test-popup-yes">Yes, I\'m sure</button>\
                    </div>')
    },
    type: 'inline',
    midClick: true,
    callbacks: {
        open: function() {
            this.content.on('click.mycustomevent', '#test-popup-no', function() { 
                alert('hello world');
            });
        }, 
        close: function() {
           this.content.off('click.mycustomevent');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks a lot cleaner, but I have yet to give it a try. I will get back to you soon. Thanks.